# Wi-fi after a fresh install

Tags: 14.04, wireless, format

i have no idea if this is an existing question in the database or not. But i simply have no time to search through it all. My question is after a fresh install will i have access to wifi right away? Or do i need to hook my computer up to a router via an ethernet cable? If so there is chance of hooking it up because the router is in the hallway wich is like i dont know 10 meters away from my computer and i dont have a cable that long.

Thank you.

TL;DR I'm about to format my computer and i need to know when i boot ubuntu up if im going to have wi-fi or not.

Comment: Boot up Ubuntu and use "Try Ubuntu" then see if wifi works.  If it doesn't, press CTRL + T to open a terminal window, enter `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and post the results.  If you have a USB wifi card use `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have wireless or not depends on your wireless hardware and the Ubuntu version you decide to install. Most common devices are covered by driver files already included in the kernel. More are added with every newer version. Therefore, the latest stable version you install, currently Ubuntu 15.10, the greater the chance that your device is covered.

Not every last device is yet covered. Manufacturers are in an arms race and develop newer, better (or worse) devices every day.

If you have some specifics about your device, we will be glad to help. The more details you can provide, the better.